# Is my understanding of completionHandler blocks correct?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Ive read quite bit about blocks by now, Apple's Guide, Cocoabuilder, 3 articles on SO and ive used examples in my code that I basically got from online tutorials.  Im still trying to understand one specific question.  So I decided to make an app with nothing more than a completionHandler example to understand better.  This is what I came up with:

ViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
[SantiappsHelper fetchUsersWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *users) {
    self.usersArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *userDict in users) {
        [self.usersArray addObject:[userDict objectForKey:@"username"]];
    }

    //WHILE TESTING postarray method, comment this out...
    //[self getPoints];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}];

}
```

SantiappsHelper.h/m

```
typedef void (^Handler)(NSArray *users);


+(void)fetchUsersWithCompletionHandler:(Handler)handler {

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myserver.com/myapp/getusers.php"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];

__block NSArray *usersArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
//dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Peform the request
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                 returningResponse:&response
                                                             error:&error];
    if (error) {
        // Deal with your error
        if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
        return;
    }

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    usersArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];

    if (handler){
        //dispatch_sync WAITS for the block to complete before returning the value
        //otherwise, the array is returned but gets zeroed out
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        handler(usersArray);
        });
    }
});
}
```

Here is what I understand...

1. I call fetchUsersWithCompletionHandler from my VC & pass it this completion block. That block takes an NSArray users parameter & returns void.
2. Meanwhile in the SantiappsHelper Class we have a variable called handler of type ^block which it receives from VC.
3. The fetchUsersWithCompletionHandler method runs, taking that CompletionBlock parameter, which itself takes the NSArray users parameter?  a little confusing.
4. The webfetch is dispatch_async so it wont block the main thread.  So execution on the main thread continues.  That new thread executes the fetch synchronously that new thread will stall until the response is returned.  Once that new thread receives the response, it fills in the NSHTTPURLResponse.  Once it returns, it fills in usersArray with the NSJSONSerialized data.
5. Finally it reaches the if test and it checks for the existence of the PARAMETER handler that was passed in? A little confusing...the parameter passed in was the completionBlock. Wouldnt that handler parameter always and obviously exist since it was passed in?
6. Once the handler !NULL then execution is returned to the main thread passing back the NSArray users expected by the block back in the VC.

But if I change the second dispatch to async, the usersArray is properly populated but once handler(usersArray) is sent back to the main thread, its empty or nil!  Why?

Answer (score 2):

1. Correct. The best way to say/think about this is to say that you are invoking a method called `fetchUsersWithCompletionHandler:`. This method will go away and do some work and at some point in the future it may execute the code you have declared in the block literal and pass in an array of users.
2. The method takes an argument called `handler` of type `void (^)(NSArray *users)`. This type represents a block of code that when invoked should receive and array and return no result.
3. The `fetchUsersWithCompletionHandler:` does some work and at some point may invoke the block passed in with an array of users as the blocks argument.
4. Correct
5. The `if (handler) {` checks to see if the handler arguments is not `nil`. In most cases this would be the case especially if you always invoke the `fetchUsersWithCompletionHandler:` with a block literal, **but** you could always invoke the method with `[self fetchUsersWithCompletionHandler:nil];` or invoked it passing along a variable from somewhere else as the completion, which may be `nil`. If you try to dereference `nil` to invoke it then you will crash.
6. Execution is not "passed back" to the main thread, you are simply enqueueing a block of work to be performed on the main thread. You are doing this with `dispatch_sync` call which will block this background thread until the block completes - this isn't really required.

The array being `nil` could be a consequence of you declaring the `usersArray` with `__block` storage. This is not required as you are not modifying what `usersArray` is pointing to at any point you are simply calling methods on it.

Comment: Appreciate your patience, im really trying here :). Ok I now understand that if the 1st dispatch is async, whatever is inside that GCD block gets initiated but execution continues onto the if(handler) test without waiting. But I have code that fetches web data and if the 2nd dispatch is async, theString which is actually an array, returns nil when back in the original calling method.  It doesnt return nil from the webfetch JSONSerialization, thats fine and populated. But when I return it to the viewcontroller method, the array is then nil.  I have to make it dispatch_sync for it to work...why?

Comment: Can you update your question with the specific code you are talking about as it may make it easier to explain

Comment: Ok so what makes it a completion block (a method that returns only when it has finished doing something heavy) is by virtue of the fact that we send it to a GCD queue and then have it return once that is done without blocking the main thread, not because the actual block has the attribute of waiting til something is done?  Iow, what makes a completion handler return when a task is done is dictated by what code is executed and how, it's not inherent to blocks?  You could have completion handlers without blocks?

Comment: @marciokoko yes you are correct - there is nothing about blocks that makes them special. Blocks just happen to be convenient for this task. Before blocks were introduced the way this was achieved was mainly through delegation - check `NSURLConnection` for a good example.

Comment: Ok so GCD is responsible for the wait until its done and then execute "THIS".  Blocks is responsible for saying what "THIS" actually is in a nice neat format?